# Do the user agents of Edge 12 and 13 differ?

Tags: user-agent, microsoft-edge

Many requests for my web page include "Edge/12" in user agent strings. None contain "Edge/13".

The [Microsoft blog](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2015/09/21/understanding-versions-in-an-evergreen-browser/) said that token string should indicate the version of Edge.

... yet my web page which gets 40K+ visits a day seems to have no visits from Edge 13 - they're all from Edge 12.

Do Microsoft's docs on Edge's user agent match what Edge 13's user agent actually is?

Well ... [this source](https://www.netmarketshare.com/browser-market-share.aspx?qprid=2&qpcustomd=0) claims that most Edge users are on 13, but how does it know that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the user agent string is different. It even contains the build number. This is the pattern for the Edge Desktop UA String:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; <64-bit tags>) AppleWebKit/<WebKit Rev> (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/<Chrome Rev> Safari/<WebKit Rev> Edge/<EdgeHTML Rev>.<Windows Build>
```

For my system this is:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2486.0 Safari/537.36 Edge/13.10586
```

An older Edge 12 UA string was:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36 Edge/12.10136
```

You can find the Microsoft documentation on this topic here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh869301(v=vs.85).aspx

I guess your user agent detection code does not detect the Edge version correctly. This proofs the point that one should avoid relying on the UA string at all.

Answer (score 1):

I work on Edge at Microsoft.

Yes, they differ. Edge 13 has Edge/13 in the UA.

For whatever reason, your traffic has not update their install of Windows.